# Is it possible to make Optional<T> and @Lazy work together in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

1. I have to make me `@Component @Lazy` as it is used rarely and creates circular dependency problem
2. I have to make it `Optional<T>` because feature it represents can be disabled on startup (`@ConditionalOnProperty`) so it might not be available at runtime

**Problem:**
**When I use `Optional<T>` as injection point, bean is initialized eagerly.**

So the questions:

1. Is it possible to make it work like that?
2. Can I replace `Optional<T>` with `Provider<T>`? will it simply return `null` if feature is disabled or it will throw exception?
3. Can it be replaced with `ObjectProvider<T>`?
4. *I would like to stick* to `@Resource` or `@Inject` annotation so `@Autowired(required=false)` will be last resort for me.

There is no code to share here actually (as it would be class and field declarations as those are relevant onl IMHO)

Since you do not belive me the code is worthless here, let me share :)

```
@Comonent
@Lazy
public class MyType{

}
```

injection point

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
private Optional<MyType> myType;
```

usage

```
  MyType instance=myType.getOrThrow(()->throw something)
```

Iv tested `Optional` and debugger hits `MyType` upon application startup. It is skipped when I use plain field, provider or object provider.

Comment: Can you show a few lines of code?

Comment: `ObjectProvider<T`>` is in my sense the way to go

Comment: Instead of injecting optional dependency why not simple provide "NULL" MyType implementation which will simply do nothing (or throw exception like in your example) in the case if corresponding feature is turned off.

Answer (score 3):

In situations like this I do not wire the `Component` directly, but lazily. There are different options:

Go through the `ApplicationContext` and retrieve `MyType` when you need it. You would only retrieve it, when you know it is enabled:

```
@Autowire
private ApplicationContext context;
...
MyType instance = context.getBean(MyType.class);
```

Provider or Factory approach, where you have an autowired service which provides you an instance of `MyType`. This service is also only called when the feature is enabled.

```
@Autowire
private MyTypeFactory factory;
...
MyType instance = factory.getMyType();
```

Using the `Provider` would require you to define a bean in your configuration, so it might be easier to just have a POJO service on which you can slap `@Service`, that does the same.

Answer (score 3):

Let me present an alternative Point of View. I think that using Optional dependency for this is not justified.

The class that has an Autowired MyType probably counts on this dependency (notwithstanding the fact that usage of Optional for data fields if a kind of bad practice).

The reason for Laziness of the component also seems to be more "hack" than intention (circular dependency is never a good thing).

So, if we'll pretend that this class makes something "Optionally available", one way is to provide an additional no-op implementation for this `MyType` problematic bean:

```
interface MyType {
   void doSomeHeavyStuff();
}

public class MyTypeRegularImpl() implements MyType {
   public void doSomeHeavyStuff() {
     ....work..work..work..
   }
}

public class NoOpMyType implements MyType {
   public void doSomeHeavyStuff() {
     // do nothing here
   } 
}
```

Now the trick is to provide two mutually exclusive conditions and make sure that only one bean out of these two loads (otherwise it will produce an ambiguity in beans and probably fail during the application startup).

So the class that uses MyType won't need Optional at all.

Now regarding the Laziness.
In general, Lazy beans only get ini
Lazy Bean can still be used since the bean will be initialized during the first call in a class that has that lazy dependency.

For no-op beans it won't matter at all.